# Is there an easy way to apply REGEXP_LIKE to path coming from connect by prior query in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, connect-by, hierarchical-query, regexp-like

I have a query including connect by prior like;

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ENAME, '/') as path
FROM EMP
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF=1
START WITH MGR IS NULL CONNECT BY
PRIOR EMPNO=MGR;
```

The result is following

```
 path
-----------------------------------
/KING/JONES/SCOTT/ADAMS
/KING/BLAKE/ALLEN
/KING/BLAKE/WARD
/KING/BLAKE/MARTIN
/KING/BLAKE/TURNER
/KING/BLAKE/JAMES
/KING/CLARK/MILLER
```

Now I want to apply regular expression(REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle) to path column to find '/KING/JONES/SCOTT/ADAMS' by '/KING/JONE'.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Obviously there isn't, it will also find the second row ('KING/JONES/FORD/SMITH'). Also, if you have a problem that makes sense (this one doesn't), why do you only want solutions with REGEXP_LIKE and not any other methods?

Comment: I am sorry for this .You are right.I changed the query result set.Please think over the last result set.Regexp_like or other methods can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE:

```
with t as (
  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ENAME, '/') as path
  FROM EMP
  WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF=1
  START WITH MGR IS NULL CONNECT BY
  PRIOR EMPNO=MGR
)
select *
from t
where path like '/KING/JONE%';
```

(in your example, `like` will do the job just fine - and faster than `regexp_like`)